# DeepLabV3: Why use global average pooling in the ASPP module?

Tags: deep-learning, image-recognition, pooling

I'm trying to understand the rationale of the various modifications the authors of the DeepLab models have made to their third version, DeepLabV3. In the paper, the following is written:

> ASPP  with  different  atrous  rates  effectively  captures
> multi-scale information. However, we discover that as the sampling
> rate  becomes  larger,  the  number  of  valid  filter weights (i.e.,
> the weights that are applied to the valid feature region, instead of
> padded zeros) becomes smaller. This effect is illustrated in Fig. 4
> when applying a 3×3 filter to a 65×65 feature map with different atrous
> rates. In the extreme case where the rate value is close to the
> feature map size, the 3×3 filter, instead of capturing the whole image
> context, degenerates to a simple 1×1 filter since only the center filter
> weight is effective. To overcome this problem and incorporate global
> context information to the model, we adopt image-level
> features, similar to [58,95]. Specifically, we apply global average
> pooling on the last feature map of the model, feed the resulting
> image-level features to a 1×1 convolution with 256 filters (and batch
> normalization [38]), and then bilinearly upsample the feature to the
> desired spatial dimension.

I do not understand how global pooling solves this problem. Is it simply because it does not suffer from the same issue of ASPP (the degeneration of the weights), and serves as an alternative?

**From:** Chen, L. C., Papandreou, G., Schroff, F., & Adam, H. (2017). Rethinking atrous convolution for semantic image segmentation. arXiv preprint arXiv:1706.05587.